# How do I input code to get the augmention matrix in beamer

Tags: beamer, pdftex

I want to obtain the two augmention matrices in beamer. How to write the code?

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 2):

One way is to use `nicematrix`.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\[\begin{pNiceArray}[xdots/shorten=1.5ex]{CCCCCCC} 
1 & \Cdots & c_{1r} & c_{1,r+1} &\Cdots & c_{1n} & d_1\\ 
\Vdots &  & \Vdots & \Vdots &  & \Vdots  & \Vdots \\ 
0 & \Cdots & 1 & c_{r,r+1} &\Cdots & c_{rn} & d_r\\ 
0 & \Cdots & 1 & 0 &\Cdots & 0 & \textcolor{red}{d_{r+1}}\\ 
0 & \Cdots & 1 & 0 &\Cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
\Vdots &  & \Vdots & \Vdots &  & \Vdots  & \Vdots \\ 
0 & \Cdots & 0 & 0 &\Cdots & 0 & 0 
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed] (col-7|-row-1) --  (col-7|-row-8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceArray}\]
\end{document}
```

[image]

This works of course also in `beamer` documents.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{nicematrix}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{An augmented matrix}

\[\begin{pNiceArray}[xdots/shorten=1.5ex]{CCCCCCC} 
1 & \Cdots & c_{1r} & c_{1,r+1} &\Cdots & c_{1n} & d_1\\ 
\Vdots &  & \Vdots & \Vdots &  & \Vdots  & \Vdots \\ 
0 & \Cdots & 1 & c_{r,r+1} &\Cdots & c_{rn} & d_r\\ 
0 & \Cdots & 1 & 0 &\Cdots & 0 & \textcolor{red}{d_{r+1}}\\ 
0 & \Cdots & 1 & 0 &\Cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
\Vdots &  & \Vdots & \Vdots &  & \Vdots  & \Vdots \\ 
0 & \Cdots & 0 & 0 &\Cdots & 0 & 0
\CodeAfter
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw[dashed] (col-7|-row-1) --  (col-7|-row-8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{pNiceArray}\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can also use `arydshln`.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usepackage{arydshln}
\begin{document}
\begin{frame}[t]
\frametitle{An augmented matrix}

\[\left(\begin{array}{cccccc:c} 
1 & \cdots & c_{1r} & c_{1,r+1} &\cdots & c_{1n} & d_1\\ 
\vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  & \vdots \\ 
0 & \cdots & 1 & c_{r,r+1} &\cdots & c_{rn} & d_r\\ 
0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & \textcolor{red}{d_{r+1}}\\ 
0 & \cdots & 1 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0\\ 
\vdots &  & \vdots & \vdots &  & \vdots  & \vdots \\ 
0 & \cdots & 0 & 0 &\cdots & 0 & 0
\end{array}\right)\]
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: The version of the tex I used is old, it reveals that the "nicematrix.sty" is not found

Comment: @mathbeginner You can either update your TeX installation or use the last solution.